# Translate into quantified logic "sally is taller than at least one of her sisters"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Translate into quantified logic "sally is taller than at least one of her sisters"

sorry i have zero knowledge on this topic ..how to write this. i confusing to what to use can some one explain me

thanks for advance

Comment: If you truly have zero knowledge on this topic, than you need to do some work before asking a question.  What have you read about quantifiers?

Comment: Use a constnt $s$ for Sally and a binary predicate $\text {Sis}(x,y)$ meaning "$x$ is the Sister of $y$" and another binary predicate $\text {Tal}(x,y)$ for "taller than".

Comment: @MatthewLeingang..one of my friend asked me this question ...i just posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can convert a natural-language statement to quantified logic by treating anything with the meaning of "at least one" as the existential quantifier "there exists" ($\exists$)," and "any/all of" as the universal quantifier "for all" ($\forall$), and restating the sentence so that the quantifier is spoken first.

Nouns can be treated as either constants or variables, and it may be necessary to change the ordering in cases where the quantified term is the object of a sentence. Verbs can be treated as $n$-ary predicates.

Assuming first-order logic, terms are quantified over sets. The set over which a term is quantified may be stated explicitly, in which case a [*bounded quantifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier) is used, or assumed, in which case the set is taken to be the [*domain of discourse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse). If $\lambda$ is the symbol for a quantifier, then a statement with a bounded quantifier is written as $\lambda\varphi(t).\psi(t)$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are unary predicates.

**Note:** In most cases, the predicate $\varphi$ will be either a declaration of set membership for some known set (ex: $\exists n\in\Bbb{N}.n<3$) or an expression indicating a subset of the domain (ex: $\forall n<3.n^2<9$). In the case of the latter, the set to which the statement applies is the intersection of the domain with the class $\{x\mid \varphi(x)\}$ - i.e. $\lambda \varphi(x).\psi(x)\equiv \lambda [x\in D\cap\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}].\psi(x)$, where $D$ is the domain.

**Random Example:** 
"All the swans in the lake are black."

"All" indicates that the universal quantifier should be used, "swans" and  "lake" are constants or variables, and "are black" acts as a predicate. If all terms are assumed to range over the set of "objects," then we would state this as "for all $x$, $x$ is a swan and $x$ is in the lake implies $x$ is black." A variation of this would be "for all $x$ such that $x$ is a swan and $x$ is in the lake, $x$ is black." If $S$, $L$, and $B$ are used to represent the unary predicates "is a swan," "is in the lake," and "is black," respectively, then symbollically we would write either $\forall x.S(x)\land L(x)\implies B(x)$ or $\forall [S(x)\land L(x)].B(x)$. The latter is a case of a bounded quantifier.

Alternatively, if $x$ ranges over the set of all swans, then we may right $\forall x.L(x)\implies B(x)$. Because the only objects under consideration are swans, it is unnecessary to stat that $x$ is a swan. Likewise, if $x$ ranges over the set of things in the lake, we may write $\forall x. S(x)\implies B(x)$.

**Your Example:** "Sally is taller than at least one of her sisters."

"At least one" indicates that the existential quantifier should be used. We have the choice of "Sally" and "Sally's sisters" as constants or variables, and "is taller than" as a predicate.

Suppose that we wish to quantify over the set of "people." The sentence, stated in first order logic, reads "there exists [a person] $x$ such that $x$ is Sally's sister and $x$ is taller than Sally." Symbollicaly, we write this as $\exists x.S(x)\land T(x,s)$, using $S$ for "is Sally's sister," $T$ for "is taller than," and $s$ for the constant "Sally."

We can write the same expression differently if we change the domain or the choice of predicates. For example, if we are working within the set of Sally's sisters, we might write $\exists x.T(x,s)$; or we could change the binary predicate "T" to a unary predicate with the meaning of "is taller than Sally." In practice, the only requirement is that the logical statement encode all information present in the natural one.